# how to create users_controller.rb with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I used `gem: devise` to create `models/user.rb` by running `rails g devise User`, and I used devise to create views by running `rails g devise:views`.  Now I want to create `controllers/users_controller.rb`. How can I do that?

```
rails g controller users
```

Is this correct? And is this user connected with `devise User`?  I looked at another app, and `class UsersController < ApplicationController` works there.

I am new.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: I try your answer, and ` rails generate devise:controllers SCOPE [options] `  and then I try ` rails generate devise:controllers users  ` and I got  `  controllers/users/some pages_controller.rb ` but no `users_controller.rb `.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some more info if it helps. What do you want to do by generating the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the `devise` controllers using its generate command:

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

The `scope` means which folder you want to create it, like if it is for users then you can give users as scope which will generate the controller in `app/controllers/users/`.

You will need to specify this in routes so that rails uses your controllers:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

If you need a controller named `users_controller` then you can generate it using:

```
rails g controller users
```

But it will not connect with `devise`. All the actions (`new`, `create`, `update`, `edit`) of `User` are handled in `registrations_controller` by devise. So you can always override them if that is what required by you. So it will call your custom code instead of the default code.

If you create your own `users_controller` it will be normal rails controller. Just define routes for it and create the views inside the users folder it will work.

More info you can find in devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do it , but I want to create app/controllers/users_controller.rb , so I can add ` def follow ? end  or def unfollow ? end `, but no that page.

Comment: So you can create it as rails does by default using this: `rails g controller users`

Comment: OK thank you very much, I doubt : ` rails g controller users ` ,from your answer , I do it . thanks a million.